# Cannot create folder in Azure blob storage $root container

Tags: azure-blob-storage

Azure storage allows for a default container called $root
As explained [in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/working-with-the-root-container)

Using the Azure Portal. When I try to upload a scripts folder to my $root container I get the error

```
upload error for validate-form.js
Upload block blob to blob store failed:
Make sure blob store SAS uri is valid and permission has not expired. 
Make sure CORS policy on blob store is set correctly. 
StatusCode = 0, StatusText = error
```

How do I fix this?

I can upload to containers that are not called $root
[image]

[Update]

I guess SAS means Shared Access Signature.
I set up the container with Blob ( anonymous read access for blobs only)
I will try Container ( anonymous read access for containers and blobs)

[Update]

Changing the access policy made no difference.
The access policy is not displayed for $root
[image]

I am aware that one must put a file in a new folder in order for the folder to create.  This is not that issue.

[Update]

Here is what my website blob looks like. I can do this for my website container but not my $root container.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Create a container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs#create-a-container) states as follows:

> - Container names must start with a letter or number, and can contain only letters, numbers, and the dash (-) character.
> - Every dash (-) character must be immediately preceded and followed by a letter or number; consecutive dashes are not permitted in container names.
> - All letters in a container name must be lowercase.
> - Container names must be from 3 through 63 characters long.

AFAIK, when managing your blob storage via [Azure Storage Client Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs), we could not create the container with the name `$root`. Also, you could leverage [Azure Storage Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-storage-manage-with-storage-explorer) to manage your storage resources, and I assume that the limitation for creating the name for your blob container is applied.

But I tested it on azure portal and found that I could encounter the same issue as you mentioned. I could create the container with the name `$root`. And I could upload files to the root virtual directory via Azure Portal and Azure Storage Explorer. I assumed that the container name starts with `$` is reserved by Azure and we could not create it. And you need to follow the limitation for container names, then you could upload your files as usual. The behavior on azure portal for creating the container name starts with `$` is unusual. You could send your feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage).

**UPDATE:**

As you mentioned about [Working with the Root Container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/working-with-the-root-container):

> A blob in the root container cannot include a forward slash (/) in its name.

So you could not create virtual folder(s) under the Root Container as the normal blob container.

For example: `https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/$root/virtual-directory/myblob`, the blob name would be `virtual-directory/myblob`, but it is invalid and you could not create it.

**UPDATE2:**

> Have you been able to create a folder within the $root container? If so can you tell me how to please.

We could not create a folder within the `$root` container, because the root container has the limitation for blob name. You could not treat azure blob storage as the file system, the folder info belongs to the blob name as follows:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I updated the question to show that $root is the name for an optional default container referencing Docs.

Comment: I am not sure if this is a bug or whether I am doing something wrong or whether I should submit a feature request.  I logged it with Microsoft at https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/5774778a-1f69-42cc-bbfb-3ead6bd6bdfb/how-do-i-upload-a-folder-to-a-root-container-inside-a-blob?forum=windowsazuredata

Comment: I updated my answer with the explanation, you could refer to it.

Comment: I am not trying to create a directory with a hypen in it. I am tring to create a simple directory inside $root for example https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/$root/script/validate-form.js  The file name has a hypen surely that is OK.

Comment: `script/validate-form.j‌​s` is the name of your blob, it contains the `/`, so it is invalid, and you could not create this blob under the root container (`$root`). For example `myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/$root/validate-form.j‌​s` is valid.

Comment: I updated the question to show what i mean.more clearly

Comment: I assumed that I have understood your question, you want to treat the root container (`$root`) as the normal blob container for uploading file(s) under a specific folder. I have explained that you need to set the **Upload to folder** empty when uploading a file to your `$root` container. Note: **A blob stored in the root container may be addressed without referencing the root container name, so that a blob can be addressed at the top level of the storage account hierarchy.**

Comment: If you want to store your resource(s) hierarchically, you need to use the normal blob container instead of the root container (`$root`).

Comment: sorry, I am not understanding you. Have you been able to create a folder within the $root container? If so can you tell me how to please.

Comment: Please see the screenshots in my answer.

Comment: I see you are correct. This design is extremely frustrating for someone used to the windows file system. I can't understand why it is all so hard.